# Get the street names with Google API

Tags: google-api

Is there a way to get all the street names in an area with a Google API? Im trying to get all the street names from Sherwood Forest, Jacksonville, Florida.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with the Google API. You could search within a 50 mile radius for places ( using the places api ) and then parse each places address for streets and exclude duplicates.

If you do not need to use google maps then I would suggest looking at this.

http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=2/71.3/-96.8

Comment: Thats a great idea.